# ubuntu linux shell scripting changing a column value of a line in textfile

Tags: linux, shell-script, ubuntu, sed

All of these are being written in case :

Case 1:

```
 echo "${name}:${identity}:${hp}:$now:"0"" >> info.txt      # write to info.txt
```

so i will have something like this : `Tom:8:987654:commission:0  # i assign it to 0 first`

Case 2 :

```
echo -n "Enter employee's name:"
read name

S=`grep $name info.txt`;    

    if test -z $S 
then
echo "No details with employee name  $name"
else
echo "$S" | cut -d: -f4 // display 4th column.
echo 
echo -n "Enter hourly wage: "; read wage;
echo -n "Enter hours worked this week: "; read hours;

pay=$hours-40*$wage;          

echo -n "To update next payroll : press Y else N to go main menu: "     

read option
case "$option" in 
[Yy]*)  echo "Payroll have been updated."
    echo grep $name | sed -i s/\:*$/$pay/n info.txt //error         
    ;;
[Nn]*) 
    echo "Press Enter to view the Main"     
esac
fi
```

My textfile looks like this:

```
Tom:8:987654:commission:0
Tommy:7:12379813:hourly:0
Fan:5:2132131:salaried:0
```

I am trying to replace the last column value to $pay ( not all columns only the specific name by the user ) Lets say the $pay is 10 and $name is Tommy

This is the expected textfile:

```
   Tom:8:987654:commission:0
    Tommy:7:12379813:hourly:10
    Fan:5:2132131:salaried:0
```

But i got this error : `sed: -e expression #1, char 15: unknown option to`s'`

i am doing in on ubuntu terminal .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace the whole line:

```
sed -e "/$name/s/[0-9]*$/$pay/" -i info.txt
```